# Failed to start kafka server in Window

Tags: apache-kafka

I downloaded the `kafka_2.13-3.0.0` in Window 10. I opened up CMD as admin. I was able to run `zookeeper` using the command `bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties`. However, when i tried to start the kafka server with the following command
`bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties`
, it gave me the following error" below. I am confused here because I can see the kafka-logs being created (see image below). Can someone help me out please ?

**Output from running Zookeeper command**

```
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,208] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\user123456~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,208] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,208] INFO Server environment:os.name=Windows 10 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,209] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,209] INFO Server environment:os.version=10.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,209] INFO Server environment:user.name=user123456 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,210] INFO Server environment:user.home=C:\Users\user123456 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,210] INFO Server environment:user.dir=C:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,211] INFO Server environment:os.memory.free=493MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,211] INFO Server environment:os.memory.max=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,211] INFO Server environment:os.memory.total=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,212] INFO zookeeper.enableEagerACLCheck = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,212] INFO zookeeper.digest.enabled = true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,212] INFO zookeeper.closeSessionTxn.enabled = true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,213] INFO zookeeper.flushDelay=0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,213] INFO zookeeper.maxWriteQueuePollTime=0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,214] INFO zookeeper.maxBatchSize=1000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,214] INFO zookeeper.intBufferStartingSizeBytes = 1024 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,215] INFO Weighed connection throttling is disabled (org.apache.zookeeper.server.BlueThrottle)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,216] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,216] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,217] INFO Response cache size is initialized with value 400. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ResponseCache)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,217] INFO Response cache size is initialized with value 400. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ResponseCache)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,218] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.slotCapacity = 60 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,220] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.slotDuration = 15 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,221] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.maxDepth = 6 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,221] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.initialDelay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,221] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.delay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,222] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.enabled = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,224] INFO The max bytes for all large requests are set to 104857600 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,224] INFO The large request threshold is set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,224] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 maxSessionTimeout 60000 clientPortListenBacklog -1 datadir \tmp\zookeeper\version-2 snapdir \tmp\zookeeper\version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,234] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,235] WARN maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,236] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 2 selector thread(s), 32 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,238] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,250] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager (org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManagerFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,250] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager (org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManagerFactory)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,251] INFO zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,251] INFO zookeeper.commitLogCount=500 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,256] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.compression.method = CHECKED (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.SnapStream)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,256] INFO Snapshotting: 0x0 to \tmp\zookeeper\version-2\snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,260] INFO Snapshot loaded in 8 ms, highest zxid is 0x0, digest is 1371985504 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,260] INFO Snapshotting: 0x0 to \tmp\zookeeper\version-2\snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,261] INFO Snapshot taken in 1 ms (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,274] INFO PrepRequestProcessor (sid:0) started, reconfigEnabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,274] INFO zookeeper.request_throttler.shutdownTimeout = 10000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.RequestThrottler)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,286] INFO Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 maxNeverUsedIntervalMs=0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ContainerManager)
[2021-12-01 20:16:17,287] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
```

**Output from running kafka command**

```
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,577] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\user123456~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,577] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,578] INFO Client environment:os.name=Windows 10 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,579] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,579] INFO Client environment:os.version=10.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,580] INFO Client environment:user.name=user123456 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,581] INFO Client environment:user.home=C:\Users\user123456 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,581] INFO Client environment:user.dir=C:\kafka_2.13-3.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,582] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=1011MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,583] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,583] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,585] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@74f0ea28 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,593] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,597] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,598] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,601] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,601] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,602] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:57191, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,617] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, session id = 0x1000008c9c20000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,619] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,720] INFO [feature-zk-node-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener$ChangeNotificationProcessorThread)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,729] INFO Feature ZK node at path: /feature does not exist (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,729] INFO Cleared cache (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,844] INFO Cluster ID = j7KyANF-S2OuLlr_IYyqDw (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,846] WARN No meta.properties file under dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs\meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,876] INFO KafkaConfig values:
...
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,918] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,919] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,919] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,920] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,931] INFO Log directory C:\tmp\kafka-logs not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,933] ERROR Failed to create or validate data directory C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.flushDir(Utils.java:953)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1(LogManager.scala:159)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:919)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.createAndValidateLogDirs(LogManager.scala:149)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:88)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1283)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:254)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-12-01 20:18:22,936] ERROR Shutdown broker because none of the specified log dirs from C:\tmp\kafka-logs can be created or validated (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

[image]

I also tried running `icacls "C:\tmp\" /q /c /t /grant Users:F`. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you tell what value has been configured for log.dirs in config\server.properties

Comment: it is `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs`. I tried changing it to `log.dirs=C:\\tmp\\kafka-logs` and `C:/tmp/kafka-logs` and still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that [3.0.0](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) has issues with Windows. I downgraded to  2.8.1 and things worked fine. I hate Windows.